# Using Spring-Data-Mongo how do I limit search?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Using Spring-Data-Mongo how do I limit search?

I am trying to find everyone over 19 but under 50 years old? the field is called "age". The following code is NOT working

```
public void countUnderAge()
{
    List<Person> results = null;

    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria = criteria.lte("21");

    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    results = mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);

    logger.info("Total number of under age in database: {}", results.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Query query= new Query();
query.addCriteria(where("age").lte(21)); 
List<Person> results = mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
```

You are missing the field name of the where clause.
You can also do:

```
Query query = new Query();
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = where("age").lte("21");
query.addCriteria(criteria);
```

To use "where" you need to add this import:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
```

Comment: the limit is not doing it by age! and I dont see less then!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I'm updating the answer